# How do I return both boolean and list from controller to view in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a search method which takes in the searched string that the user inputs, and return a list of strings with the name that starts with the searched string.
My method contains both boolean isSearch VARIABLE AND the search string itself
No, it is not a duplicate since another question asks about the model while mine asked about individual values respectively. isSearch is a boolean variable not found in any model.

```
       public IActionResult Search(string search)
    {

        bool isSearch = true;

        var ssList = Database.SessionSynopses.Where(x => 
     x.SessionSynopsisName.StartsWith(search)).ToList();


        return View(isSearch, ssList);

        }
```

However, it throws me an error `bool cannot be converted to string`
I have tried all ways to return an object to the views, including viewbag, but none of them has worked so far.

Comment: You create a view model containing those 2 properties (`bool isSearch` and `List<SessionSynopses>`) and pass that to the view

Comment: Of course its a duplicate! And read the above comment! - pass one model to the view containing all the data your need!

Answer (score 0):

Use **ViewBag**, like this

ViewBag.Search = isSearch;

ViewBag.List= ssList;

And get these values on view in same way

@ViewBag.Search to get ***isSearch***
and
@ViewBag.List to get ***ssList***

Comment: I'd better use ViewBag only for secondary information, providing main data to the model. E.g. `ViewBag.Search = isSearch; return View(ssList);`

Comment: Better use a ViewModel instead of ViewBag. Properties in ViewBag must always be casted back to the original type, this is not necessary with ViewModel. Also, you can make a View require a certain ViewModel which can prevent some runtime errors.

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider why?

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider yeah ViewModel is also a way to do it. But it's all up to you to pick any way to do so...

Answer (score 0):

You can return **[Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx)** as,

```
Tuple<bool, List<CustomType>> tuple = new Tuple<bool, List>(boolValue, list);
return View(touple);
```

You also have to set the model type as `Tuple<bool, List<CustomType>>` inside your view for this.

PS: You cannot use `Touple` if your view is to edit the data, as mentioned by Stephen in comment.

Comment: If the view is for editing data, then you cannot use a `Tuple`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for pointing that!